# Values in one column but not in other

Tags: excel, vba

VBA question: I have two columns in excel:

```
A   B
10  6
5   1
6   4
2   7
8   9
4   8
9   10
7   5
    3
    11
```

Now I need the result to contain those value which are in column B, but not in column A. I know that I can use CountIf to solve the problem. However, is there any way that I can do it in VBA without looping?

Comment: Why do you want to do this in VBA without looping?

Comment: Because my data is too big and looping takes so much time!

Comment: You can't avoid looping here, but you could reduce the time it takes by sorting the data in column A and doing a binary search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range, rngA As Range, rngB As Range
    Dim lastRowA As Long, lastRowB As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")  'change Sheet3 to your data range

    With ws
        lastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row   'last row with data in Column A
        lastRowB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row   'last row with data in Column B
        Set rngA = .Range("A2:A" & lastRowA)                 'range with data in Column A
        Set rngB = .Range("B2:B" & lastRowB)                 'range with data in Column B

        .Range("C2").Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF(" & rngA.Address & ",$B2)=0,B2,"""")"   'enter formula in Cell C2
        .Range("C2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("C2:C" & lastRowB)                'drag formula down
        .Range("C2:C" & lastRowB).Value = .Range("C2:C" & lastRowB).Value           'keep only values
        .Range("C2:C" & lastRowB).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp 'delte blank rows
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: @BlueFx - Oops! I just noticed you want solution without using loop.

Comment: yeah, I want the solution without using loop, anw, thank for posting

Comment: Perfect, it shortens half the time needed, thanks, Mrig

Answer (score 2):

Try with Below Formula,
in D2 place the below formula, select D2 to D11 and Press CTRL+D.

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(B2,A:A,0))=TRUE,B2 & " Not Exist in Column A", B2 & " Exist in Column A")
```

**OP**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun (and speed), you can also do that with SQL :

```
Sub SqlSelectExample()
'list elements in col C not present in col B
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    con.Open "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};" & _
           "DriverId=790;" & _
           "Dbq=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
           "DefaultDir=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";ReadOnly=False;"
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "select ccc.test3 from [Sheet1$] ccc left join [Sheet1$] bbb on ccc.test3 = bbb.test2 where bbb.test2 is null  ", _
            con, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
    Range("g10").CopyFromRecordset rs   '-> returns values without match
    rs.MoveLast
    Debug.Print rs.RecordCount          'get the # records
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

You will have to rework the SQL a bit.

Comment: Thank for posting but I want the solution in pure VBA code (I know SQL or R can do better job)

Comment: This is VBA ! And by the way, replies on SO are supposed to be interesting also for people other than the OP :-)